# DNN 9 how to set up SSO data services for a custom authentication provider

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, dataservice, dotnetnuke-9

I am setting up a DDn9 Website. I am installing a custom authentication provider.
I was following this tutorial:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134678/dotnetnuke-tips-and-tricks-12-creating-your-own-authentication-provider

However, I am having issues with the login.

A critical error has occurred. Please check the Event Viewer for further details.

```
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:736a7a78-8497-4859-94f6-440094888df5
AssemblyVersion:9.1.0
PortalId:2
UserId:-1
TabId:43
RawUrl:/******************/
Referrer:
UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
ExceptionHash:yVCuLxbZ4VPBRUjk/HkzfItVk9U=
Message:GetVendorToken.SSOServicesHelper :: The type initializer for 
'SIAM.DataServices.SSOServicesHelper' threw an exception.
StackTrace:
InnerMessage:GetVendorToken.SSOServicesHelper :: The type initializer for 
'SIAM.DataServices.SSOServicesHelper' threw an exception.
InnerStackTrace:
at SIAM.DataServices.SSOServicesHelper.GetVendorToken(String ssoRedirectUrl) 
at SIAM.DataServices.SSOServicesHelper.ConstructSSOURL(String ssourl, String 
ssoRedirectUrl) at SIAM.DNN.Modules.SimpleLogin.View.Page_Load(Object 
sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at 
DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I think there is something wrong with my linkage in the web.config file. I was wondering if you need a tutorial or an example that would show up the web.config file was a  set up for custom authentication provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little debugging should be able to help you identify what isn't being initialized correctly.

Comment: When I debugged I got  the error is at 

            vendorToken = SvcProxy.VendorTokenEncrypt(SSOVendorUsername, SSOVendorPassword, SSOVendorBlock, ssoRedirectUrl);

It is the SvcProxy that is null. which means this doesn't create it:

 private static readonly serviceSoapClient SvcProxy = new serviceSoapClient(SSOServiceEndpoint, SSOWebReferenceURL);

Both SSOServiceEndpoint and SSOWebReferenceURL are correct and set in the web.config. So i think there is something else i forget to set that deals with sso or xml serialization....